# Socket.io Doesn't work on IE8

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Hi I had developed a small app with nodejs and socket.io so that I can utilize push mechanism of socket.io.

It works like charm on Firefox, Chrome and Safari but fails to work on IE8.

Am getting this error 
[`WebSocket] cannot connect to Web Socket server at ws://socketio-example.nodester.com:80/socket.io/1/flashsocket/1574670559846521853 (SecurityError) make sure the server is running and Flash socket policy file is correctly placed`

After lot of googling I got the information to set the transports on socket.io and I limited only to

```
io.set('transports', [
'jsonp-polling'
]);
```

After this I am not seeing the error but contents are getting loaded.

If I want to really set up Falsh policy file what is it exactly and where I should put it.

Struggling with this for long time now need some suggestion on this.

This is my server side code for reference

```
var app = require('express')
    //var  httpapp = require('http')
, fs = require('fs')
 //http = require('http').createServer(httpapp)
, server = require('http').createServer(handler)
, io = require('socket.io').listen(server)
, firstTime;

//httpapp.get('*',function(req,res){ 
//    res.redirect('https://itcomm-dev.vmware.com:8080'+req.url)
//})
io.set('flash policy port', 10483)
io.set('transports', [
   //  'websocket'
   //, 'flashsocket'
//   , 'htmlfile'
//   , 'xhr-polling'
    'jsonp-polling'
 ]);
//io.set('flash policy port', -1)
io.set("polling duration", 60)
server.listen(8083);

// on server started we can load our client.html page
function handler(req, res) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/../index.html', function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      //console.log(err);
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end('Error loading client.html');
    }
    res.writeHead(200, {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*','Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE',
                        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'X-Requested-With, Accept, Origin, Referer, User-Agent, Content-Type, Authorization'});
    res.end(data);
  });
}


io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
  //console.log(__dirname);
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/../scripts/notifications.json', 'utf-8', function(err, data){
      if(err) throw err;
      socket.volatile.emit('notification', data);
  })

  try{
    fs.watch(__dirname + '/../scripts/notifications.json', function(curr, prev) {
      // on file change we can read the new xml
      fs.readFile(__dirname + '/../scripts/notifications.json','utf8', function(err, data) {
        if (err) throw err;
        // send the new data to the client
        socket.volatile.emit('notification', data);
      });
    });
  }
  catch(err){
    throw err;
  }

});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25348679/problems-with-socket-io-on-ie8-and-9

Comment: Tried that but no luck on IE8